# User Activation Code doesn't activate after submitting an Update query

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I'm working on a project using ZEND

A very strange and non-logical thing keeps on happening.

When user registers it generates an activation code an writes to DB:

```
//Generate Activation Code;
$activation_code = date('YmdHis');
$activation_code .= substr(number_format(time() * rand(),0,'',''),0,10);
```

in the database i get for ex. code like this: **201212301653302670595490**

User should go to link  `/user/activation/201212301653302670595490`

I get this param with the controller:

```
public function activateAction() {

$activation_code = htmlentities(trim($this->_getParam('activation_code', 0)));
$activation_code = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","", $activation_code);


    $usersModel = new Users_Model_DbTable_Users();
    $result = $usersModel->activUser($activation_code);

    if($result) {

        $this->view->message = 'Your account is activated. You may now Login.';

    } else {

        $this->view->message = 'Something went wrong.';

    }
}
```

this action calls a function in my models:

```
public function activUser($activation_code) {

    $data = array(
        'status' => 2
    );

    if($this->update($data, 'activation_code = '. $activation_code)) {
        return true;            
    }

}
```

this is the custom rout in my Bootstrap:

```
$activateUserRoute = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route("user/activate/:activation_code", array(
   'module' => 'users',
   'controller' => 'manage',
   'action' => 'activate'
));

$router->addRoute('activateUserRoute', $activateUserRoute);
```

my cell **activation_code** in DB table is VARCHAR with Length of 24 ('cuz the generated code in 24 symbols in length).

**The awkward moment**

it keeps failing the activation process. it always returns false;

if I go to DB, replace generated code with any number 1, 1231231231234 or even the generated code itself (201212301653302670595490) it does the activation.

Maybe you can tell me what's going wrong in here? any practice?

Comment: Mikey, do you have a custom route setup?  The action `activation` in the url `/user/activation/201212301653302670595490` doesn't match your  action `activate`. If we can see what route you are using, then we can determine what the value of `$this->_getParam('activation_code', 0)` will be.

Comment: @toneplex yes I have my custom route, the problem is that it works fine, with any value that I directly write in the Table through phpMyAdmin, and it works fine with the first entry (I mean when there's only 1 user in the table). I updated the question with Custom route.

Comment: try changing the update statement to the following 
`$where = $this->getAdapter()->quoteInto('activation_code = ?',    $activation_code);
if($this->update($data, $where) {
    return true;            
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gotta aske this one first:

What is the point of: `$activation_code = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","", $activation_code);` it looks like you are replacing all of the values in your activation code with nothing.

The way you passed the activation code to the [$where parameter](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.table.html#zend.db.table.update) has been deprecated. In some places that syntax may still work in others it doesn't.

```
public function activUser($activation_code) {

    $data = array(
        'status' => 2
    );
    $where = $this->getAdapter()->quoteInto('activation_code = ?', $activation_code);
    //update() returns number of rows updated,
    if($this->update($data, $where) === 0) {
        return false;            
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Because `update()` returns the number of rows updated any untrue condition in your current `if()` statement would be inaccurate. IT may work correctly most of the time...
It would be even better if you tested for exactly the number of rows that are supposed to be updated and fail if that number is not returned.

`htmlentities()` may not be the best choice to filter your input parameter. You may be much better off filtering for the type of data that you know is there. [Zend_Filter_Input](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.filter.input.html) has filters and validators that can be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.profiler.html to see SQL that is generated.